# Переход к следующему треку в mediplayer

Tags: java, android

```
Переход к след. треку по завершению текущего осуществляю так:
public class PageFragment extends Fragment implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    //массивы мелодий
    private int[] soundsRawResIds = new int[]{R.raw.belarus, R.raw.russian, R.raw.japan,
            R.raw.litva, R.raw.england, R.raw.finlandia, R.raw.france};
    //каждой кнопке присвоена своя мелодия
    private int[] buttonIds = new int[]{R.id.b1, R.id.b2, R.id.b3, R.id.b4, R.id.b5, R.id.b6, R.id.b7};
    private int[] fragments = new int[]{R.id.imageView1, R.id.imageView2, R.id.imageView3};



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        fab();
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);


        playerText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textPlayer);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.clickbutton);
        potehanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.potehkianim);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootViewB = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.sbar);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.button_play);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        startMediaPlayer();
        setSeekBar();
        playAllSongs();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);


        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            arr_imageA[i] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(fragments[i]);

            arr_imageA[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    v.startAnimation(potehanim);

                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.imageView1:
                            startActivity(getActivity(), a1.class);
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView2:
                            startActivity(getActivity(), a2.class);
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView3:
                            startActivity(getActivity(), a3.class);
                            break;

                    }
                }
            });

            if (pageNumber == 1) {
                for (int index = 0; index < buttonIds.length; index++) {
                    arr_imageB[index] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(buttonIds[index]);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < arr_imageB.length; j++) {

                    arr_imageB[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            stopAnimation();
                            switch (v.getId()) {
                                case R.id.b1: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);

                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case R.id.b2: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[1]);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case R.id.b3: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[2]);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case R.id.b4: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[3]);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case R.id.b5: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[4]);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case R.id.b6: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[5]);
                                    break;
                                }
                                case R.id.b7: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[6]);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
                return rootViewB;
            }
        }
        return rootView;
    }
//обновляю сеекбар
    private Runnable onEverySecond = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (seekBar != null) {
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            }

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                seekBar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
            }

        }
    };

//воспроизвожу мелодии из case
    public void startMediaPlayer() {

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                seekBar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });

    }

    public void setSeekBar() {
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBars, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }


            }
        });
    }
//метод в котором по нажатию на кнопку играют все мелодии из массива(подряд)
    public void playAllSongs() {

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.startAnimation(anim);
               idx = (idx + 1) ;
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(soundsRawResIds[idx]);

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    afd.close();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
//запуск активти с задержкой
    public void startActivity(final Context activityContext, final Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(activityContext, activityClass));
            }
        }, 200);
    }



    public void stopAnimation() {
        for (int index = 0; index < buttonIds.length; index++) {

            arr_imageB[index].clearAnimation();

        }
    }

    private void playSample(int resid) {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            stopAnimation();

        } else {

            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                afd.close();


            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

    }

//отключение звука
    public void setVolume(float left, float right) {
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(left, right);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        /*if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        }*/
        Notify();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();

    }
}
```

Comment: Так вы ж сетод этот нигде не вызываете... А сам по себе как он может вызваться? Вам, видать, надо слушатель окончания сначала повесить на плеер...

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб
ну как бы сам класс у меня имплементирует:
public class PageFragment extends Fragment implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
добавил в onCreateView
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
ничего не изменилось

Comment: Попробуйте ещё где-нить повесить его

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,  onCreateView по логике же нужно?
пробовал и в  onCreate так же ничего,т.е песня закончилась,сеекбар не сбросился в перв. положение,а если еще раз нажать ан кнпоку,то играет след.мелодия...

Comment: Написал ответ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сначала надо повесить на плеер слушатель окончания.
2. В слушателе окончания надо не слушатель нажатия на кнопку вешать, а перезапускать плеер.

Comment: ,изменил код в шапке,надеюсь,что я правильно Вас понял..результат тот же...не играет след.трек по заверш. предыдущего

Comment: делал по этому примеру:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383387/setting-an-array-of-songs-using-mediaplayer

Comment: Посмотрите в свой код. Вы вместо запуска след песни назначаете слушатель кликов на кнопку

Comment: Вы как всегда выручаете!Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

@ЮрийСПб точно подметил - неповешенный на объект листенер событий не свяжется с N'ым MediaPlayer'ом сам, поэтому [вешайте](http://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.media.MediaPlayer/setOnCompletionListener).

А строка из лога - это вообще, насколько помню, чисто отладочная информация, никак не связанная с жизненным циклом проигрывания аудио через медиаплеер.

Comment: это я знаю.
public class PageFragment extends Fragment implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {